# Content pulled via Headless Selenium Chromedriver does not reflect dynamically updating content on webpage (as it does in "headful" mode)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless

**TL;DR: content from a webpage that is known to dynamically update over time only updates in the headful Chromedriver, but does not dynamically update if the Chromedriver is headless. How can I preserve the headful updates in the headless driver condition?**

I am using Python Selenium (version=3.141.0) Chromedriver (chromedriver version = 104.0.5112.79; browser version = 105.0.5195.125) to pull information from websites that dynamically update their content over time in the absence of explicit browser refreshes, e.g:
https://www.paddypower.com/football?tab=in-play

If I run a "headful" Chromedriver (e.g. *without* passing the headless=True argument when instantiating the driver)  and pull the data, the pulled content reflects the updated information over time without having to explicitly refresh the page, i.e. every time I pull I get the most up-to-date information without having to run driver.refresh() (note my pulls simply send JavaScript commands via the driver to the webpage to pull all text from specific elements)

However, if I run my exact same data pulls but now with a headless Chromedriver, I can only ever pull the information that was displayed on the page at the time of the driver's deployment, and repeated pulls after this do not reflect changes in that page's information over time *unless* I explicitly refresh the page (now using driver.refresh()).

Note I want to avoid explicit page refreshes as they can take significant time, and I want to avoid using headful Chromedrivers as I want to open several pages simultaneously.

I routinely pass the following arguments to Chromedriver, none make a difference:

```
    options = Options()
    options.headless=headless
    options.add_argument('window-size=2000x1500')

    options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')
    options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'");
    options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu');
    # bypass OS security
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    # don't tell chrome that it is automated
    options.add_experimental_option(
        "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    # disable images
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

The Chromium developers recently added a 2nd headless mode that functions the same way as normal Chrome.

`--headless=chrome`

(the old way was: `--headless` or `options.headless = True`)

The New Headless Mode Usage:

```py
options.add_argument("--headless=chrome")
```

You should be able to use that mode and get the same results as headed mode.

There's more info on that here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36

Comment: Amazing, this solved it - thanks so much! Content in headless mode now dynamically updates over time with this flag.

Answer (score 0):

To provide extra help to the answer provied by Michael Mintz is very good.

Create a headless browser like so:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--headless=chrome")
```

It's good to note that when this crashes, the browser will still be open. In this case, trying to open a new browser might result in an error if you are using chrome user profiles:

```
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

It'll just be invisible and might be difficult to close. It can be closed by the following:

```
import os

os.system("taskkill /f /im geckodriver.exe /T")
os.system("taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe /T")
os.system("taskkill /f /im IEDriverServer.exe /T")
```